# C++ why that code has that output? I would love to ubderstand what is hapening inside

Tags: c++

Why this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define DIFF(x,y) x-y

int main()
{
    std::cout <<   DIFF(5,3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << 1*DIFF(5,3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << 2*DIFF(5,3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << 3*DIFF(5,3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << 4*DIFF(5,3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << 5*DIFF(5,3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << 6*DIFF(5,3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << 7*DIFF(5,3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << 8*DIFF(5,3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << 9*DIFF(5,3) << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

has that output?
2
2
7
12
17
22
27
32
37
42

I cannot undestand what is happening inside and cant find documentation about it

Comment: I guess you expect 2*(5-3) but you get 2*5-3

Comment: Interesting, but why it doesnt do (5-3) and then *5?

Comment: Macros are not functions but a straight text replacement in the source code, so `2*DIFF(5,3)` expands to `2*5-3`

Comment: * has higher precedence than -. Remember that macros are fancy string search and replace before compilation. This is why it is recommended to parenthesize your macro expressions.

Answer (score 0):

DIFF is a c preprocessor definition. The c preprocessor is a text processor that doesn't know anything about c.
It basically copy-pastes the definition of DIFF into the code before compilation. That means that

```
    std::cout << 2*DIFF(5,3) << std::endl;
```

becomes

```
    std::cout << 2*5-3 << std::endl;
```

Which is 10-3 = 7

To solve this you could add parentheses like `(x-y)` in your define.

Or, since you are using c++, you might want to use a `consterxpr` function like this:

```
constexrpr int DIFF(int x,int y){ return x-y;}
```

which has the advantage of type safety, and namespace scoping etc.